# Bearer Token and session mangement

Tags: token

I'm working for a company and I saw their authentication mechanism and wasn't sure if it's good.

When the user first logs in, the credentials will be sent to the server and the server will generate a Bearer Token and response, then on the client-side, the token will be saved in the cookies.

If the client asks for something, the Bearer header will be attached to the request, but every time the user logs in, a new token will be generated, so all the generated tokens from previous times still work.

I don't think this is good practice right? Initially, I'm planning to delete the token when the user logs out. What do you think?

Comment: This is basically how OIDC works. The server sends the end session request to the Identity Provider that revokes the access token in cookies and the user is logged out.

Comment: but in my case when the user clicks logout just the token from cookies will be deleted

Comment: You are supposed to revoke the token.

Comment: So my idea was to delete the token from the server when the user clicks logout, but not invalidate it - since a new token would be generated anyways when the user login even if the user didn't logout- would this be a problem?

Comment: It should be invalidated until it's expired. Once the expiry date is crossed, you can delete it from the server.

Comment: since at the end they will be deleted anyways why would I invalidate them ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/136979/discussion-between-defalt-and-mr-c).